# A simple yii2 function doesn't work

Tags: php, yii2

I have two functions, which has the same purpose, but I wrote it differently. The first one works fine, but the second one - doesn't work and I can't see the difference between them. Could someone explain me why the second one doesn't work properly?

1. ```
   public function getClientPhone()
   {
   if (is_null($this->client_id)) {
       return '';
   }

   $phone = Client::getStaticClientPhone($this->client_id);

   if (is_null($phone)) {
       return '' ;
   }

   return $phone;
   }
   ```
2. ```
   public function getClientPhone()
   {
   $phone = Client::getStaticClientPhone($this->client_id);

   if ($this->client_id || $phone === null) {
       return '';
   }

   return $phone;
   }
   ```

Comment: "*..second one doesn't work properly*" Any Error??

Comment: This: `if ($this->client_id` returns true as long its value is not 0

Comment: I don't get any errors. It's just doesn't printing the values (phone number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
if ($this->client_id || $phone === null) {
    return '';
}
```

To

```
if ($this->client_id === null || $phone === null) {
    return '';
}
```

Or

```
if (!$this->client_id || $phone === null) {
     return '';
}
```

Comment: Meh, thank you, it worked. Could you tell me which function would be more correct? Which one should I use?

Comment: I think, 2nd one is better. @HarryFlopper